# SSIS task failed event handler

Tags: ssis

Is there any way in SSIS to identify which particular task has failed? My requirement is on file source task failure I need to send an email.

Comment: You have entered basically the same question three times... yet you don't accept the good answers you do get...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your error handler, you can use the System::SourceName variable to pull the name of the task it was on when it failed. I do this in an email task to the production support team. Or you could put it in a table if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Your log should be able to tell you which task failed and (in most cases) why it failed as well.

You can add an OnError Event Handler to handle failure gracefully as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following variables in  error handling 
In the email task:

System::SourceName

System::ErrorCode

(DT_WSTR, 4000) @[System::ErrorDescription]